# How do I model a pixel-wise regression convnet? What kind of loss should I use?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, confidence-interval, convolution, transposed-convolution

Given an input of (HxWxD), I want to output a confidence map of size (HxW) where each value is a probability.

I'll try to be concise.
I have 2 inputs:

- input_image of size (HxWx3)
- input_map of size (HxWx1), that was generated by a vision algorithm with "input_image" as its input.

The algorithm that generates input_map from input_image is not very precise (some values are wrong).
The purpose of the network is to assign to each input_map pixel a confidence value, meaning that for each pixel of input_map I want to output the probability of it being calculated correctly or not.

At training time I have a groundtruth_confidence_map:

For groundtruth_confidence_map (HxWx1), where each pixel can assume the value:

- 0 (corresponding input_map pixel is wrong)
- 1 (corresponding input_map pixel is right)
- -1 (data for that pixel is unavailable) , which could be used as a mask when calculating the loss.

What kind of loss do I use? How should I model the output layers of the architecture?